# How to store data from firebase to analyze at some later date

Tags: database, storage

I am currently using Firebase with my iOS app. I use it to authenticate users and then allow user interactivity during the life of the app session. I would like to be able to save a snapshot of my firebase data anytime that a value is changed, so that at some future time I can analyze all this data and use it to view how my users are using my app.

How am I supposed to do this? I am thinking that I need some "cloud code" on Firebase that will observe value changes on whichever Firebase URL endpoint i specify. Then It would need to take this snapshot and send it somewhere for persistent storage... I am thinking Amazon Simple Storage? Which I could then go into later and use some language, like Python for example, to analyze all the snapshots from the past?

I would really appreciate any advice or pointers in the right direction, thanks

Comment: Make sure you obtain affirmative consent from your users before you attempt this.

Comment: Yes i will for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the logging functionality in your app and let it just store copies of modified data into another node (may not be right term) on firebase. This prevents you from having some other app running all the time.

Then write some sort of other administration app where you can manually run it to pull down all this logging data for analysis. After that, you can clear it out based on some time/date filter. If the amount of data you're storing is an issue, you'll have to do this more often.

The limitation here is going to be how much data your app requires and how much extra coding the logging would require. You can always start with a part you think is more critical and then log more areas of the app as you go along. I do realize this is not ideal in a situation where you're required to have your app go through an app store process. You're in a much better position if you haven't had your app approved yet.

Comment: This is an avenue I considered, I just didnt think it was best practice. I thought maybe there was a standard approach in this situation since it seems like something every developer would want to be able to do. But thanks for the advice

Comment: Having apps log what they do is pretty standard. Putting the logs in your database may not be, but in this case, I don't see log files as being ideal. Another option is to build your app so the data are immutable, so you never delete or update a record, just add a new one with different data and program logic to determine which record is current.

Comment: Would my idea be an unreasonable amount of work? To use like Heroku, for example, to deploy some code that will observe changes to data at my firebase endpoint, and just grab and save a snapshot every time that happens?